# Moving a toilet sideways?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Buying a home. Renovating a bathroom with concrete slab for a floor. Specifically need to move the toilet at least 12" to the right. After the toilet is moved we'll install a LONG 2 sink vanity. I do NOT want to cut another hole in the slab and would like to avoid putting the toilet on a raised wood platform. My thought was to move the toilet over 12" and plumb it in back over to the existing closet drain and then the new vanity will cover that piping. There, easy and all I need to do is find a toilet that would allow me to do that. So my research showed me a left hand discharge drain toilet. It has the discharge hole coming out the left side of the toilet horizontally about 6" +/- above the floor. Cool, I thought, but I can't seem to find anywhere that sells them in the USA. So then I thought I'd go with a back discharge toilet but the ones I found have to be attached to the wall. Any ideas would be much appreciated...Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome if  you could send pics of work area ,  It would help a lot and a drawing of your layout ...  Also what size  drain pipe do you have sounds like there was a toilet before .

Comment: https://www.upflushtoilet.com/products/saniflo-saniplus. The saniflo toilet could be an answer if all else fails

Comment: http://www.hugooliver.com/shop/toilets/close-coupled-toilets/arlo-left-or-right-side-exit-close-coupled-toilet-with-seat/.  Is this the one you found?

Comment: A skew trap or skew pan toilet is the search term I found for such a toilet. Australia  New Zealand UK Japan but none in USA. Interesting question. Learned something new here.

Comment: Kris- Yes, that's the one I found but it's in Europe...Wonder why we don't sell them in the  US...? The other one with the floor level tank won't work...

Comment: Robert- We're not closing on the house til the 14th and I didn't take pics in my prior visits. Had it all in my head =-) Thank you both for your input....

Comment: In the U.S. this would be considered a hack and probably would not pass a home inspection for sale at a later time. Cutting concrete is an easy job, depending on the type of pipe is not hard but some times are tougher cast requires a Fernco no hub then connect to abs soil pipe and bring up to a closet flange, less changes in direction less plugging, if already abs it is even easier and depending on the condition of the existing closet flange only a 2’ pice of pipe and 2 couplings would be needed. You will have less drain issues while you live there and no problems with a sale at a later date.